# Is my understanding of limit point compactness correct with respect to $[0,1]^{\omega}$ with the uniform topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

The following is an exercise problem about limit point compactness from the book "Topology" by Munkres (2nd edition).

> Exercise 1 in Section 28: Give $[0,1]^{\omega}$ the uniform topology. Find an infinite subset of this space that has no limit point.

[Here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/e02/3gt/opg/S28.pdf) is a solution:

> Let $d$ denote the uniform metric. Choose $c \in (0,1]$. Let $A = \{ 0, c \}^{\omega} \subset [0,1]^{\omega}$. Note that if $a$ and $b$ are distinct points in $A$ then $d(a,b) = c$. For any $x \in X$ the open ball $B_d(x, c/3)$ has diameter less than or equal $2c/3$, hence $B_d(x, c/3)$ cannot contain more than one point of $A$. It follows that $x$ is not a limit point of $A$.

I am confused about the following points:

> 1. The open ball $B_d(x, c/3)$ has diameter less than or equal $2c/3$.` Why is *equal* here possible?
> 2. Why not consider the points $x \in A$ and $x \in X \land x \notin A$ separately? After all, for any point $x \in X \land x \notin A$, we have to show that there exists a neighborhood around $x$ which does not intersect $A$ (instead of just showing that the ball $B_d(x,c/3)$ cannot contain more than one point of $A$).

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An open ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ has the diameter $\sup\{d(y,y')\mid d(y,x)<ϵ,d(y',x)<ϵ\}$. Since any such pair $y,y'$ has a distance $<2ϵ$ by the triangle equality, the $\sup$ can be $2ϵ$
2. Note that $[0,1]$ is Hausdorff, so $[0,1]^\omega$ is Hausdorff, too. It follows that if some neighborhood of $x\in X$ contains only finitely many points of $A\setminus\{x\}$, then there is some neighborhood of $x$ containing none of them.