# Prob. 1, Sec. 28 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: An infinite subset of $[0,1]^\omega$ without limit points in the uniform topology?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness, solution-verification

Here is Prob. 1, Sec. 28, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Give $[0, 1]^\omega$ the uniform topology. Find an infinite subset of this space that has no limit point.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680900/is-my-understanding-of-limit-point-compactness-correct-with-respect-to-0-1) is a Mathematics Stack Exchange post on this very problem.

My Attempt:

> We note that $[0,1]^\omega$ denotes the set of all the sequences $\left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of the real numbers $x_n$ in the closed unit interval $[0,1]$, and that the uniform metric $\bar{\rho}$ on $[0,1]^\omega$ be given by 
>   $$
> \bar{\rho}\left( \left( x_n \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} , \  \left( y_n \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \right)  \colon= \sup \left\{ \ \min \left\{ \ \left\vert x_n - y_n \right\vert, 1 \ \right\} \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \  \right\} \tag{A} $$ 
>   for all $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }, \left(y_n \right)_{ n \in \mathbb{N} } \in [0,1]^\omega$.
>
> We show that $[0,1]^\omega$ is not limit-point-compact
>
> Let 
>   $$A \colon= \left\{ \  (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \ \colon \ x_n \in \{ 0 , 1 \}  \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\} = \{ 0, 1 \}^\omega. \tag{B} $$
>   This set $A$ is an infinite subset of $[0, 1]^\omega$.
>
> We show that the set $A$ has no limit points in $[0,1]^\omega$.
>
> Let $ \mathbf{x} \colon= (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, \mathbf{y} \colon= (y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in A$ be any two distinct points. Then 
>   $x_n, y_n \in \{ 0, 1\}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_k \neq y_k$ for at least one $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and for this $k$, we have $x_k - y_k = \pm 1$. Therefore we find that 
>   $$ \bar{\rho} \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right) \geq \left\lvert x_k - y_k \right\rvert = 1, $$
>   but we know from (A) above that 
>   $$  \bar{\rho} \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right) \leq 1; $$ therefore 
>   $$ \bar{\rho} ( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} ) = \bar{\rho}\left( (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, (y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \right) = 1. \tag{1} $$
>   for any two distinct points $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in A$.
>
> Let $\mathbf{p} \colon= \left( p_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be any point of $[0, 1]^\omega$. We now show that this point $\mathbf{p}$ cannot be a limit point of set $A$.
>
> Case 1. Suppose that $\mathbf{p} \in A$. Let us take any real number $\epsilon$ such that $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Then for any point $\mathbf{a} \in A$ such that $\mathbf{a} \neq \mathbf{p}$, we must have
>   $$ \bar{\rho} ( \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{p} ) = 1 > \epsilon, $$
>   because of (1) above. Therefore 
>   $$ \left( A \cap B_{\bar{\rho}} ( \mathbf{p}, \epsilon ) \right) \setminus \{ \mathbf{p} \} = \emptyset. $$
>   So $\mathbf{p}$ is not a limit point of $A$.
>
> Case 2. Suppose that $\mathbf{p} \in [0, 1]^\omega \setminus A$. Then there exists at least one $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $p_N \not\in \{ 0, 1\}$; for that $N$ we have $0 < p_N < 1$. Now let us take any real number $\epsilon$ such that 
>   $$ 0 < \epsilon < \min \left\{ \ \frac{p_N}{2}, \frac{1-p_N}{2} \ \right\}.  $$
>   Then
>   $$ \epsilon < \frac{p_N}{2} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \epsilon < \frac{1-p_N}{2}, $$
>   and so 
>   $$ - \frac{p_N}{2} < - \epsilon  \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \epsilon < \frac{1-p_N}{2}, $$
>   which in turn implies that 
>   $$ \frac{p_N}{2} = p_N - \frac{p_N}{2} < p_N - \epsilon  \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad p_N + \epsilon < p_N + \frac{1 - p_N}{2} = \frac{p_N + 1}{2}. $$
>   In fact we obtain 
>   $$ 0 < \frac{p_N}{2} < p_N - \epsilon  \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad p_N + \epsilon < \frac{p_N + 1}{2} < 1. \tag{2}$$
>   Now if $\mathbf{x} \colon= \left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ in $[0, 1]^\omega$ satisfies 
>   $$ \bar{\rho}( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{p} ) < \epsilon, $$
>   then for that point $\mathbf{x}$ we also have 
>   $$ \left\lvert x_N - p_N \right\rvert < \epsilon, $$
>   which implies that 
>   $$ p_N - \epsilon < x_N < p_N + \epsilon, $$
>   which together with (2) above implies that 
>   $$ 0 < \frac{p_N}{2} < p_N - \epsilon < x_N < p_N + \epsilon < \frac{p_N + 1}{2} < 1, $$
>   and thus 
>   $$ 0 < x_N < 1, $$
>   from which it follows that $\mathbf{x} \not\in A$. Thus we can conclude that 
>   $$  A \cap B_{\bar{\rho}}( \mathbf{p}, \epsilon ) = \emptyset, \tag{3}$$
>   and so 
>   $$ \left( A \cap B_{\bar{\rho}}( \mathbf{p}, \epsilon )\right) \setminus \{ \mathbf{p} \} = \emptyset. $$
>   Thus $\mathbf{p}$ is again not a limit point of our set $A$. In fact, $\mathbf{p}$ is not even an *adherent* point of set $A$.
>
> From (3) we can even show that our set $A$ is in fact a closed set in $[0, 1]^\omega$.

Am I right?

> Finally, it is my understanding that the above proof can go through even if we take our set $A$ as follows: Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be any two distinct real numbers such that $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ and $\beta \in [0, 1]$. Then let us put 
>   $$ A \colon= \left\{ \ \left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \ \colon \ x_n \in \{ \alpha, \beta \} \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\} = \{ \alpha, \beta \}^\omega. \tag{B*} $$

Is my proof correct and clear in all its details? If not, then where is it in need of improvement?

Comment: Small simplification: if $x_n,y_n\in[0,1]$ then $\min(|x_n-y_n|,1)=|x_n-y_n|$.

Comment: Probably duplicate: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680900/is-my-understanding-of-limit-point-compactness-correct-with-respect-to-0-1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680900/is-my-understanding-of-limit-point-compactness-correct-with-respect-to-0-1)

Comment: @drhab can you please have a look at my post now? I've made a lot of changes to it.

Comment: @WillardZhan can you please take time having a look at my post now? I've tried to improve my proof.

Comment: This seems a bit overly complicated. Just take $A$ to be made of all sequences $x^{(N)}$, where $x^{(N)}_N = 1$ but $x^{(N)}_k = 0$ for $k \neq N$. Then all the points in $A$ are at distance 1 from one another, so it does not have a limit point. To be precise with this last part of the argument: if there is a limit point $p$, then there are infinitely many elements of $A$ in $B(p,1/2)$; but then all elements in this ball are at distance $<1$ from one another.