# Prob. 4, Sec. 29, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: $[0, 1]^\omega$ with uniform topology is not locally compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, solution-verification

Here is Prob. 4, Sec. 29, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Show that $[0, 1]^\omega$ is not locally compact in the uniform topology.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293328/how-to-show-that-0-1-omega-is-not-locally-compact-in-the-uniform-topology) is a Math Stack Exchange (MSE) post that is of course relevant. However, here I would like to present my own attempt:

First of all, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375326/prob-1-sec-28-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-an-infinite-subset-of-0-1-ome) is an MSE post of mine on $[0, 1]^\omega$ with the uniform topology.

> Suppose if possible that $[0, 1]^\omega$ with the uniform metric topology *is* locally compact.
>
> Let 
>   $$ \mathbf{a} \colon= \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},  \ldots \right). \tag{Definition 0} $$
>
> As $[0, 1]^\omega$ is locally compact at point $\mathbf{a}$, so there exists a compact subspace $C$ of $[0, 1]^\omega$ and an open set $U$ in $[0, 1]^\omega$ such that
>   $$ \mathbf{a} \in U \subset C. \tag{0} $$
>
> Now as $U$ is an open set in the uniform metric space $[0, 1]^\omega$ and as $\mathbf{a} \in U$, so there exists a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ B  ( \mathbf{a}, \delta ) \subset U, \tag{1} $$
>   where
>   $$ B ( \mathbf{a}, \delta ) \colon= \{ \, \mathbf{x} \in [0, 1]^\omega \, \colon \,  \bar{\rho}( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{a} ) < \delta \, \}. \tag{ Definition 1 } $$
>   Since reducing $\delta$ will make the set $B ( \mathbf{a}, \delta )$ smaller, we can assume without any loss of generality that our $\delta$ satisfies 
>   $$ 0 < \delta < \frac{1}{2}. \tag{1*} $$
>
> From (0) and (1) above we also obtain 
>   $$ B ( \mathbf{a}, \delta ) \subset C. \tag{2} $$
>
> Since $C$ is a compact subspace of the Hausdorff space $[0, 1]^\omega$ with the uniform metric topology, therefore $C$ is also closed in $[0, 1]^\omega$, by Theorem 26.3 in Munkres.
>
> Now as $C$ is a closed set in $[0, 1]^\omega$ and as $B ( \mathbf{a}, \delta ) \subset C$ by (2) above, so we also have
>   $$ \overline{B ( \mathbf{a}, \delta ) } \subset C, $$
>   that is,
>   $$ \bar{B} ( \mathbf{a}, \delta ) \subset C, \tag{3} $$
>   where 
>   $$ \bar{B} ( \mathbf{a}, \delta ) \colon= \{ \, \mathbf{x} \in [0, 1]^\omega \, \colon \,  \bar{\rho}( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{a} ) \leq \delta \, \}. \tag{ Definition 2} $$
>
> Moreover, as $\bar{B} ( \mathbf{a}, \delta )$ is a closed set in the compact space $C$, so $\bar{B} ( \mathbf{a}, \delta )$ is also compact, by Theorem 26.2 in Munkres.
>
> Finally, as  $\bar{B} ( \mathbf{a}, \delta )$ is a compact (metrizable) space, so it is also limit point compact, by Theorem 28.1 in Munkres.
>
> Now let us take 
>   $$ \alpha \colon= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\delta}{2}, \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \beta \colon= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\delta}{2}. \tag{Definition 3*} $$
>   And, then let us define the set $A$ as 
>   $$ A \colon= \{ \, \alpha, \beta \, \}^\omega. \tag{Definition 3 } $$
>   Then $A$ is an *infinite* subset of $\bar{B} ( \mathbf{a}, \delta )$, but $A$ has no limit points in $\bar{B} ( \mathbf{a}, \delta )$, as has been shown in my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375326/prob-1-sec-28-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-an-infinite-subset-of-0-1-ome). This contradicts the fact that
>   $\bar{B} ( \mathbf{a}, \delta )$ is limit point compact.
>
> Thus our supposition at the start of this proof is wrong. Hence $[0, 1]^\omega$ in the uniform topology is *not* locally compact.

Is this proof correct? Is it easy enough to understand? Or, are there issues of accuracy or clarity?

Answer (score 2):

I think the proof is fine, and easy enough. It's a generalisation of the idea to show the unit ball in $\ell^\infty$ not being compact.

Such infinite-dimensional linear-like spaces will almost never be locally compact.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you must have $\overline{B(a,\delta)}=\overline{B}(a,\delta)$? In general you just have $\overline{B(a,\delta)} \subset \overline{B}(a,\delta)$.

In fact, you can use $\delta$ small enough to make $\overline{B}(a,\delta) \subset C$.